# Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have computer, A, with a PHP program that connects and manipulates DB in computer B1. For the connection to the MS SQL server, I use the following script, which works well. There is only one account on this SQL server, and it is "sa".

`$server = 'WAREHOUSE1\MYDB';`

`$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "sa", "PWD" => "something", "Database"=>"MYDB");`

`$dbcMssql = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);`

We got a new computer, B2, to replace this computer because it was old and slow. I set up the new DB and restored it from B1's, set up firewall settings just like in B1, checked "allow remote connection" and selected "SQL Swrver and Windows Auth. mode" in MS SQL Server Management Studio, etc.. I am able to connect on the DB's on computers B1 and B2  from computer A using MS SQL Server Management Studio. I've even linked the tables to MS Access (OBDC database) using the same user id ("sa") and password.

The problem is that on the new computer, B2, my PHP script doesn't work anymore, even though I can connect to it using the MS SQL program. I don't recall setting up anything other than what I've already done when I was setting up B1. The error is as follow from `sqlsrv_errors()`.

`[SQLSTATE] => 28000`

`[code] => 18456`

`[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'.`

The error is not logged for some reason in the errorlog file on the server folder for some reason, so I don't know what the state of the error is.. What could be the problem? I have read several articles this entire afternoon, but I'm unable to make this work! Again, connection to B1 from A is fine, which leads me to believe that I didn't set something on B2. B1 and B2 have same version SQL servers.

Comment: Is MYDB the instance name, or the database name?  Also, you shouldn't use 'sa' for this; make a new account.  Check to make sure the database server accepts Mixed Mode Authentication per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

Comment: I would wager $100 that the password for `sa` is ... `sa` ;)

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs: MYBD is the instance name and database name (are they not the same things?). I checked your link, but Win7 Home doesn't have secpol.msc.. is it not enough have to have mixed authentication mode set on the SQL server, though, as I described in the OP?

Comment: Definitely not the same thing... if you did not create a named instance of MYDB when installing SQL Server, your server name should just be the name of the machine.  If it's SQL Express, you may need to call it 'WAREHOUSE1\SQLEXPRESS'.

Comment: WAREHOUSE1/MYDB is correct, which ever of the two this is. This is how I get connected to this DB (on B2) in MS SQL Server Management Studio. It sounds like this is the instance name? If so, I need to find out what the database name is.. I'll run a query tomorrow to find out the DB name.

Comment: Just found out from `select @@ServerName` that the `serverName/instanceName` is actually something else. instanceName is the same, but serverName is a previous computer name (computer name was changed from WAREHOUSE0 to WAREHOUSE1). However, when I use `$server = 'WAREHOUSE0-PC\MYDB';`, the program cannot even locate this instance. I'm gonna change the computer B2's name back to WAREHOUSE0 and see if that does anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRC the TCP/IP protocol is disabled by then default installation. You need to go to SQL Server Config and enable it from there.

Edit: Ok, just read it again, and if you are able to connect remotelly via TCP/IP then it should work from your PHP script aswell. Are you sure the connection string ends up pointing at the right (B2? )server ? Can it be a name resolution issue?

Comment: Is there another way of checking/setting the TCP/IP protocol instead of using SQL Server Config? When I open up the Config Manager, "MYDB" instance is not listed on neither computer B1's or B2's installation for some reason. It shows other DBs on the computers, but not MYDB.

Comment: Open Sql Server Configuration Manager. Under SQL Server Network Configuration you should have a "Protocols for MYDB". Can't imagine having another way of turning that on. Could it be some sort of access rights ? Just to be sure SQL Server Conf should be started as Admin

Comment: I tried "run as admin" as well and it is still not there in SQL Server Config. Manager (Local) -> SQL Server 2005 Network Config.. I only see "Protocols for UPSxxx", which is a DB for a UPS program. Could it be some sort of version issues of MYDB instance? I have a feeling it's some sort of permission issue.. but I'm logged in Win7 as the admin.

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked the database name.. It was "MYDB_v2". "_v2" was appended when my coworker installed the software on the new computer.. So, as you said, it was a name resolution issue. I feel dumb. Here, I learned that instance and database names are different things. I was told they're not the same, but I didn't know what the difference was. After finding out how to audit failed logins, I noticed that it would make the connection, but it would fail to connect to MYDB. That's when I took a closer look at the names..